# Is there a way for a Google cloud function to know it is running in the Firebase emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to change function behavior depending on if it is running in production or not. Is there a way to check? I've tried `admin.instanceId().app.options.projectId`, `env.process.GCLOUD_PROJECT` and they both give the production ID, not something related to the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === 'true'`